# Monotonicity properties of Poisson distributions

Tags: pr.probability

During my current research [on inventory management policies, i.e., something really applied ;-) ] I am trying [since quite some time already] to prove a certain monotonicity result for Posson distributions - it would be great if someone could help:

Denote by $p(i) = \frac{m^i}{i!}e^{-m}$ the Poisson probability for $i$ when the rate paramter equals $m$. I am trying to prove the following for $x \in \mathbb{N}$

$\big( \sum_{i=x+1}^\infty p(i) \big) \cdot \big(\sum_{i=0}^{x-1} p(i) \big) \leq p(x) \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \min(i,x) \cdot p(i)$

*Many thanks in advance!*